# Reference Request: Original $\Gamma$-convergence Paper

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

Does anyone know what the original paper/work of Ennio de Giorgi, where $\Gamma$-convergence first appeared is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the first one was

*"Convergenza di alcune successioni d'integrali del tipo dell'area.*"

published in a series of papers  dedicated to Mauro Picone on the occasion of his ninetieth birthday. It appeared in

*Rendiconti di Matematica e delle sue Applicazioni (6) 8 (1975), pp. 277–294*

Comment: Super!! Merci Claude :)